# Does new instance need to be created for delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

I was just playing with delegate but I got confused about working of it.
In below code

```
public delegate void HelloFunctionDelegate(string Message);

public static void Main()
{
    //HelloFunctionDelegate del = new HelloFunctionDelegate(Hello1);
    //del("hello from delegate");
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");       
    Hello(Hello1);      
}

public static void Hello(HelloFunctionDelegate del)
{
    del("This is it");//we did not create instance of delegate 
}

public static void Hello1(string strMessage)
{
    Console.WriteLine(strMessage);
}
```

Here It is working in both ways.we can pass method by creating new instance (commented code)and without creating new instance of delegate (HelloFunctionDelegate )? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. Even if it looks like you are not creating a new instance of a delegate, **you are still *implicitly* creating a new instance of a delegate,** via a [method group conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#method-group-conversions).

Here:

```
Hello(Hello1);
```

A method group conversion converts the method group expression `Hello1` to an instance of the delegate type `HelloFunctionDelegate`, as specified in the spec:

> The result of the conversion is a value of type `D`, namely a *newly created delegate* that refers to the selected method and target object.